# PropertyAnimation based on a State

Tags: qt, qml

I'm wondering whether I can use a PropertyAnimation based on a particular State.

```
`StateGroup {
     states: [
        State {
            name: "alignment";
            when: text.width < 200;
            PropertyAnimation { 
                   target: text;  properties: "horizontalAlignment"; from: Text.AlignHCenter; to: Text.AlignLeft }
          }
     ]
}`
```

I want to achieve something like the above code but I don't know whether it is possible to do such thing.

Comment: The main problem is that `horizontalAlignment` is not a property that can be interpolated because it is an enumeration. You would need to do something like use a layout and have `text` be anchored to the center and then animate anchors.horizontalCenterOffset. If you get that worked out, then the place to put animations during state changes is in Transitions. More info here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-transition.html Give it a try and update your question with the code you come up with.

Comment: you can use [AnchorAnimation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-anchoranimation.html) instead.